# Understanding the attack on IIS virtual hosting

Tags: iis, virtualhost

I'm reading https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aeNq_5wVwHRR1np1jIRQM1hocrgcZ6Qu/view?pli=1

On page 44 it mentions about a way to exploit IIS servers,

[image]

I tried to reproduce it but it didn’t work.

1. I created a Windows 2016 IIS server and add a virtual directory /test/ and placed a file in it, and I can access it via hxxp://127.0.0.1/test/ok.txt.
2. I created another file "bug/bug.txt" outside wwwroot folder.

But I can’t access bug.txt via `hxxp://127.0.0.1/test/..%2fbug/bug.txt`. Is there any special configuration necessary to reproduce this issue?

Answer (score 1):

> But I can’t access bug.txt via hxxp://127.0.0.1/test/..%2fbug/bug.txt. Is there any special configuration necessary to reproduce this issue?

Allowing access to things outside the webroot would be a vulnerability. Thus you need a vulnerable server.

It's [ancient and likely patched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27829537/iis-403-forbidden-with-2f-in-the-url) in 2016 and IIS10.